# Tableau Excluded Data - Calculated Fields and Overlapping Time Periods

Tags: tableau-api, overlapping, calculated-field, period

I want to plot revenue for two time periods "Last 30 Days" and "Last 60 Days" on the same diagram. The problem is that for "Last 60 Days" all the data that already is in "Last 30 Days" will not be included.

This is due to my IF clause which looks like this:

```
IF [Auftragsdatum] >= DATEADD('day', -30, NOW()) AND [Auftragsdatum] <= DATEADD('day', 0, NOW()) THEN 'Last 30 Days'
ELSEIF [Auftragsdatum] >= DATEADD('day', -60, NOW()) AND [Auftragsdatum] <= DATEADD('day', 0, NOW()) THEN 'Last 60 Days' 
END
```

Does anybody know how to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a calculated field called **revenue_last_30_days** defined as

`IF  DATEDIFF('day', [Auftragsdatum], TODAY()) <= 30 AND
    [Auftragsdatum] <= TODAY() THEN [Revenue] END`

Create a second calculated field called **revenue_last_60_days** defined as

`IF  DATEDIFF('day', [Auftragsdatum], TODAY()) <= 60 AND
    [Auftragsdatum] <= TODAY() THEN [Revenue] END`

Plot both measures as desired, probably using the pseudo fields Measure Names and Measure Values to specify your viz.

If you don't ever have future revenue in your data, you can drop the test checking to be no later than today -- since that will always be true.